# Exposing internal web application to Internet

Tags: security, networking

we have an internal web application currently with in our company's network but going forward there are some external vendors that will push the data to this internal webapp. Instead of making the internal web app exposed to internet (which will make these vendor sw communicate)is there any alternate better way to expose webapp for these limited vendors I'm thinking of setting up a reverse proxy infront of this internal web app and proxying requests. Is that good idea ?

Comment: I see your question is already several month old, what did you do in the end ?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to set a rule in your firewall to allow only the ip addresses of your vendors to access the necessary part of your website.

And you can have a reverse proxy on the top of that.